# ImageList throwing me outofbounds exception at ImageList.RemoveAt()

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to make a matching game in WinForms with C#. I looked at this MSDN project: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd553230.aspx. I replaced the icon list with an imagelist. According to this article my images should show up twice per image. But whenever it hits the same number again it says that it's out of bounds, this is what I think is happening. Here is my code:

```
    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        imageInit();
        imgToLbl();
    }

    Random rndImage = new Random();

    ImageList images = new ImageList();

    //list of file names
    List<string> files = new List<string>()
    {
        "Bavaria", "Denemarken", "Engeland",
        "Frankrijk", "Nederland", "oostenrijk",
        "Polen", "Pruissen", "Rusland", "Schotland",
        "Spanje", "Zweden"
    };

    // Method to put the files into the imagelist
    private void imageInit()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            images.Images.Add(files[i], Image.FromFile("../../images/" + files[i] + ".png"));
        }
    }

    // method to assign the images to a label in my form
    private void imgToLbl()
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
        {
            Label imgLbl = ctrl as Label;
            if (imgLbl != null)
            {
                int rndNum = rndImage.Next(images.Images.Count);
                images.ImageSize = imgLbl.Size;
                imgLbl.ImageList = images;
                imgLbl.ImageIndex = rndNum;
                imgLbl.ImageList.Images.RemoveAt(rndNum);// this is where the exception is being thrown
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the full exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of '8' is not valid for 'index'.

I have a feeling that this should be easy but I can't figure out how to fix this exception. There's also another thing. The colors are all messed up and I don't know why.

Here is the original:

[image]

Here is the messed up one which is being shown in the app:

[image]

Can someone please help me?

Comment: what is the value of rndNum and ImageList.Images length?

Comment: It can be anything from 0 to 12. it varies when I run it, hence the Random I created

Comment: it should be 0 to 11

Comment: But it should still be in bounds and not out of bounds

Comment: You had to debug and see what's the value of `imgLbl.ImageList.Images` when you remove the item.

Comment: The quality is limited by your setting of ColorDepth in a imagelist.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria it was -1 somehow before it crashed

Comment: If you have two questions, ask two questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to remove the images from the Labels ImageList that you've just assigned to it. You will eventually end up with 0 entries in the ImageList and Labels still referencing indexes. your assignment of imgLbl.ImageList is a *reference* to the already existing ImageList object, it is not cloning it and as such when you remove an entry from its list it is removing it for every label already assigned the instance. You want to clone the list (or better yet) maintain 1 full list and ensure you dont pick the same number twice.

Answer (score 1):

- You are destroying the images in the `ImageList` but you still want the `Lables`, `ListItems` etc.. to refer to them. This can't work

You need to keep them around as long as any control or other item needs to display them.

You see that you are assigning just a number as the `ImageIndex`. This number points into the `ImageList` and therefore the image still needs to be there..

- Also: The quality is limited by your choice of `images.ColorDepth`. Set it to `Depth32Bit`! The default is only `Depth8Bit`